# Change image once function which has ajax has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am wanting an image to change to a loading symbol when clicked, and then change back when the AJAX functions are finished.

I've got the below, however it is not changing at all (well, it is changing, but immediately changing back without waiting for the ajax call to finish). Why is this happening? Is this because my ajax call is enclosed in a function?

```
  //adding product to cart
  $("body").on("click", "#cart_product_add", function() {
    var clickedIcon = $(this);
    //show the spinning loader
    var loader = $(clickedIcon).attr("src").replace("add_icon.png", "green_loading.gif");
    $(clickedIcon).attr("src", loader);    

    var code = $(clickedIcon).data("product_code");                  
    var description = $(clickedIcon).data("product_description");
    var whqc = $(clickedIcon).data("product_whqc");
    var qty = $(clickedIcon).prev("input[name=qty]").val();

    $.when(
      addCartProduct($("input[name=cart_id]").val(), code, description, whqc, qty)
    ).then(function() {
      loader = $(clickedIcon).attr("src").replace("green_loading.gif", "add_icon.png");
      $(clickedIcon).attr("src", loader);
    });

  });
```

Comment: You will have to show us the code for `addCartProduct()`.  Does it return a promise?   `$.when()` is not magic.  You HAVE to pass it one or more promises for it to do its job.

Comment: @jfriend00- I did not know that. I will look more into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.when()` can only do its job if you pass it one or more promises.  It doesn't have any magic ability to know when an ajax call inside the function you pass it is done.  So, if you don't pass it a promise, it just executes then `.then()` handler immediately and doesn't wait for anything (which is what you're seeing).

Since jQuery Ajax calls already return a promise, you probably can just return that promise.  And, if you only have one operation you're waiting for, there's no reason to use $.when either.  Here's a skeleton for how you could do it:

```
addCartProduct($("input[name=cart_id]").val(), code, description, whqc, qty).then(function() {
    loader = $(clickedIcon).attr("src").replace("green_loading.gif", "add_icon.png");
    $(clickedIcon).attr("src", loader);
});


function addCartProduct() {
    return $.ajax(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could help you
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/

you can specify this once and it triggers for every ajax request.

Comment: Each Ajax call has it's own completion function or you can use the promise it returns.  Much better to use those.